# How to combine information from a stored Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2005

I have a Commission report function that grabs ALL the daily sales info for an employee.  `fCommissionINFO`  What I would like to do is grab different information based on the output and create a commission report.  For example the function grabs number of total customers, description of specific sales.  What i'd like to do is count the number of total sales, the total number of specific sales, and the percentage of specific sales.  So for example... If "Sara" has "100" total sales... Of those 100 sales, she has 3 of service "x" (total of 3%), 5 of service Y (5%), 6 of service "z" (6%) etc. etc...

My initial 2 stored function calls are:

```
Select UserName, SUM(CarCount) AS Cars
FROM dbo.fCommissionINFO(@startdate, @endate, 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', 'ALL', 'Combined', '0') AS fCommissionINFO_1
WHERE (Services > 0)
GROUP BY UserName
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(Description) AS [service x]
FROM dbo.fCommissioninfo(@startdate, @endate, 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', 'ALL', 'Combined', '0') AS fCommissionINFO_1
WHERE (Description = 'service x')
```

How can I combine these, and combine a third to line up with the username?

Answer (score 1):

You need this query

```
 SELECT UserName,            
        (SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN Description = 'service x' THEN 1  END)) OVER() * 100) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Services] > 0 THEN CarCount END) AS percentage
 FROM dbo.fCommissioninfo(@startdate, @endate, 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', 'ALL', 'Combined', '0') AS fCommissionINFO_1
 GROUP BY UserName
```

Simple example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10228)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select UserName, SUM(CarCount) AS Cars, COUNT(Description) AS [service x]
FROM dbo.fCommissionINFO(@startdate, @endate, 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', 'ALL', 'Combined', '0') AS fCommissionINFO_1
WHERE (Services > 0)
GROUP BY UserName, Description
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should do the trick.  Note the hoisting of the where clause to inside the counts.  This is because if there was a row that had a services <= 0 and a description of 'service x'it would be excluded by the top query and included in the bottom query.  So by simply combing the queries you could get different results depending on your data.

```
Select UserName, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Services > 0 THEN CarCount ELSE 0 END) AS Cars,
COUNT(CASE Description = 'service x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM            dbo.fCommissionINFO(@startdate, @endate, 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', 'ALL', 'Combined', '0') AS fCommissionINFO_1
GROUP BY UserName
```